# Burpsuite and Tails OS

Tags: tails

I am running Bursuite Community Edition on Tails 5.11

I have downloaded firefox-esr and have set all ports to 127.0.0.1:6666 which is what I have set burpsuite proxy to listen on. I have also manually generated the certificate file and imported it into firefox. It still keeps giving me the error that the proxy is refusing connections. I have added the SOCKS5 proxy in bursuite as well and have it on 127.0.0.1:9050 which tor is open on. I have also tried setting an upstream proxy in burpsuite to no avail. Help please.

Answer (score 0):

It's just another case of the question here - read the predecessors for your answer https://tor.stackexchange.com/search?q=burpsuite

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment, but no, it in fact is not 'just another case of the questions here' believe it or not I can read and checked existing posts before posting. If a link exists on the subject I have read it please kindly only add original knowledge in the future as to be productive.